# How to remove the header of a single dropdown in bootstrap when it changes to a button for mobile

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, menu, nav, dropdown, hamburger-menu

I have a simple nav bar with logo on left and the word Menu on right that act as a dropdown. For small screens I need it to change the menu wording to a burger icon. So far I can get it to change to an icon but the list still contains the word menu and thats still a dropdown. How do I make it so the list only contains the items on the dropdown and not the dropdown itself?

```
<div class="container-fluid">
<div class="navbar-header">
  <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
  </button>
  <div class="logo pull-left animated wow fadeInLeft"><a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html"><img src="LOGO" alt="" title=""></a></div>
</div>
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
  <li class="dropdown">
      <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Menu<span class="caret"></span></a>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li><a href="#">Page 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Page 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Page 3</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Please show your html and css. Not sure what you have but maybe <span class="hidden-xs">Menu</span>?

Comment: I have updated it with the HTML now, CSS is from bootstrap